# Spring storing an object in session

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

After logging with a user object, the user will be able to choose one of their multiple accounts, once the user select one of his accounts I want the application to work with that specific account. Is there any way to store a object account in session with spring so as to **any controller** can have access to that variable at any time?

Comment: Maybe read [this](http://richardchesterwood.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/using-sessions-in-spring-mvc-including.html).

Comment: If you are using Spring Security (which is what the selected tags suggest) you can use the build-in Switch User functionality which makes it transparent and quite easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **session beans**.

First an interface to set and get your object:

```
public interface AccountHolder {
    public void setAccount(Account account);
    public Account getAccount();
}
```

Then an implementation of the interface:

```
public class AccountHolderImpl implements AccountHolder {
    private Account account;
    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }
    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }
}
```

Define a session-scoped bean in your `@Configuration`:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public AccountHolder accountHolder() {
    return new AccountHolderImpl();
}
```

After that you can simply use the following in your controllers:

```
@Autowired
private AccountHolder accountHolder;
```